# Why not say mishna (M'nachos 61) means to exclude R' Y'huda?

Tags: bikkurim-first-fruits, maseches-menachos

There's a dispute between *tanaim* as to when the *bikurim* were waved (*t'nufa*): *Rabi Eliezer ben Yaakov* says they were were waved during *viduy*, while *Rabi Y'huda* says they were waved after *viduy*. (According to *Tosafos*, [*Suka* 47:2](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1191&size=1), *Rabi Y'huda* may agree they were waved during *viduy* also, and the *Sifre* says they were waved both during and after *viduy*, but, anyway, *Rabi Eliezer ben Yaakov* holds they were waved only during *viduy*.)

*Rambam* rules in his *Mishne Tora* like *Rabi Eliezer ben Yaahov*.

Now, in [*M'nachos* 61:1](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4510&size=1), the *mishna* says "אלו טעונות תנופה ואין טעונות הגשה לוג שמן של מצורע ואשמו והבכורים כדברי רבי אליעזר בן יעקב", that *bikurim* require waving "as *Rabi Eliezer ben Yaakov* says". [The *g'mara*](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4511&size=1) asks why it says "as *Rabi Eliezer ben Yaakov* says" if *Rabi Y'huda* also holds *bikurim* are waved, and offers two answers.

Why doesn't it answer "because it means *bikurim* are waved during *viduy* only"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end of the Tosfos implies that there are 3 opinions.  Keeping it simple:

1. **Rabbi Elazar ben Yaakov**- waving during the viduy
2. **Rabbi Yehuda**- waving after the viduy
3. **3rd tanna** (aka rabbanan)- no waving

If the purpose of the mishna in Menachos 61a was to describe the bikurim process, then the reference to Rabbi Elazar would indicate a waving in line with R"E rather than that of R"Y.

But the Mishna is merely a list of the limited cases where there is waving, but no approaching (hagasha).  *When* you do the waving is irrelevant  to the purpose of the mishna.  But it isn't clear that bikurim is on this list because of the 3rd tanna.  so the mishna has to reference a tanna that does require waving.  The gemara's question is why list bikurim based on R"E, the mishna could have accomplished the same thing using R"Y.

Comment: Do I understand your answer correctly to be "the _g'mara_ didn't say the _mishna_ meant to exclude _R' Y'huda_'s view because the _mishna_ wouldn't be talking about when waving was done at all, focusing instead on whether waving was done"? (Just making sure I get it.)

Comment: That's my impression given your information.

Comment: Also, @msh210, there is this to consider: none of the other cases in the mishnah there involve viduy or any kind of verbal declaration. So indeed the mishnah doesn't have to be taking a position on whether the waving was during the viduy or after it.

Comment: YDK, okay. Thanks much, and +1. @Alex, right, but if we're wondering why the _mishna_ chooses one _tana_, that could well be the reason. (Especially inasmuch as — as the _g'mara_ doubtless knew — we rule like _Rabi Eliezer ben Yaakov_.)